# Java Rotate object around center point?

Tags: java

Hello I am making a programme that shows you the different planets in space.
I have the sun in the very center of the window and all the planets around it.
I want the planets to rotate around the sun but I have no idea how I could do this. Please help me. Here is the code where I draw the planets and sun onto the screen:

```
public class Solar1 extends BasicSystem {

private Image img;

public int px = 300,py = 300,px1 = 200,py1 = 200;


public Solar1() {

}

public void tick() {

}

public void render(Graphics g) {

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("res/bg/bg1.png");
    img = i.getImage();
    g.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);

    ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/planets/sun.png");
    img = i2.getImage();
    g.drawImage(img, Comp.size.width / 2 - 50, Comp.size.height / 2 - 50, null);

    ImageIcon i12 = new ImageIcon("res/planets/blue.png");
    img = i12.getImage();
    g.drawImage(img, px,py, null);

    ImageIcon i1112 = new ImageIcon("res/planets/green.png");
    img = i1112.getImage();
    g.drawImage(img, px1,py1, null);

}

}
```

Comment: Simplest approach I think think of is to design circular orbits for planets. Assign an orbital velocity to each planet. (For simplicity, think in terms of milliseconds to complete spin around orbit). You can line up all your planets along Y axis at the beginning. And assuming your render method runs let's say 40 times in a second, you calculate new position of each planet and render its location accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int i=0;

        while(true){
            planet1.setX(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)))*widthOfFrame;         
            planet1.setY(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)))*heightOfFrame;
            i++;
        }
```

...where i is the number of iteration. You will also need to find out how to set the speed, distance from the central point, etc...